# How to dismandle the existing admin login page from the Spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Need to remove the Admin login page from the existing Spring mvc project without code scan issues

Tried with jsp changes and controller method changes but it will create scan issues

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.